# Assigning onclick event to global variables - javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

I have many divs with class "mypoll". Here is my js code:

```
var mypoll=[];

$(document).ready(function (){      
    mypoll=document.getElementsByClassName("mypoll");
});

for(var t=0; t<mypoll.length; t++) {
    mypoll[t].getElementsByClassName("deletePoll")[0].onclick=(function() {
        var currentI = t;
        return function() { 
            deletedMyPoll(currentI);
        };
    })();
}
function deletedMyPoll(i){
    var a=document.getElementsByClassName("mypoll")[0].innerHTML;
    alert(a);
}
```

The error I get is

```
cannot set property onclick of undefined.
```

I have the exact same piece of code on my project (it is big and complicated and I can't post it  all here) but it doesn't work.

It works on the jsfiddle though.

Is there any problem with the global variables in javascript? Can I use them that way?

[jsfiddle.net/Vwtmu](http://jsfiddle.net/Vwtmu)

Thank you

Comment: let's start with properly indenting

Comment: he meant next time you should improve code formatting before posting the question ;) Why don't you share the fiddle with us?

Comment: right! http://jsfiddle.net/Vwtmu/

Comment: Your fiddle does **not** work because you did not let it use jQuery. Take a look at the console and you will see `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use jQuery, you might as well use it:

```
$(".mypoll").on('click', '.deletePoll', function () {

});
```

Comment: ok but it's just that i don't know at all jquery and i ll mess up the whole project.

Comment: can i use what you wrote and pass a parameter in the onclick function?

Answer (score 0):

The for loop runs before the dom is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function (){      
    mypoll=document.getElementsByClassName("mypoll");

    for(var t=0; t<mypoll.length; t++) {
        mypoll[t].getElementsByClassName("deletePoll")[0].onclick=(function() {
            var currentI = t;
            return function() { 
                deletedMyPoll(currentI);
            };
        })();
    }

});
```

Comment: Please read what the error message is. It has nothing to do with whether `mypoll` is set or not. If that was the case, the `for` loop wouldn't iterate, because `mypoll.length` would be 0. The error message is "cannot set property onclick of undefined". The only place `onclick` is used is on `mypoll[t].getElementsByClassName("deletePoll")[0]`, which means THAT is `undefined`

Comment: i put some of the loops in $(document).ready(function (){ and it worked! Do I have to do it for every loop? I am saying that because all the loops are already in a big $(document).ready(function (){

Comment: actually it does have to do with you poll,  document.getElementsBy* will not work if the actual elements is not on the dom yet. have you tried using my exact code?

Comment: I used almost the same as yours. I ll try again and come back to you. SO , we are sure that js reaches the dom before it is created? Even if i have the whole code (not only the loop itself) wrapped with  $(document).ready( ??? thank you